# How to yield list element to create dict value

Tags: python

I,m trying to create a dict value from my_list1, the key comes from mylist, how can i make multiple calls to a function witch contains the list and only return 1 element of the list on each call, at the moment I only get the last element from the list returned for the given key.

How can i achieve this?

```
my_list = ['BBC 1 HD', 'BBC ONE HD', 'BBC TWO HD', 'ITV', 'Sky Sports F1 
HD']

my_dict = {}

def Get_My_list1():
    yield from ["BBC One HD",
              "BBC Two HD",
              "ITV",
              "SkySp F1 HD"]

for channel in my_list:
    i = Get_My_list1()
    for v in i:
        my_dict[channel] = v

print(my_dict)
```

The output i get is the following

```
{'BBC 1 HD': 'SkySp F1 HD', 'BBC ONE HD': 'SkySp F1 HD', 'BBC TWO HD': 
'SkySp F1 HD', 'ITV': 'SkySp F1 HD', 'Sky Sports F1 HD': 'SkySp F1 HD'}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please show us what you want `my_dict` to contain given those input lists.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve, this is how your generator function should work:

```
def Get_My_list1():
    for i in ["BBC One HD",
           "BBC Two HD",
           "ITV",
           "SkySp F1 HD"]:
        yield i
```

Comment: In Python 3, it's simpler to use `yield from some_list`.

Comment: Blotosmetek that just gives me the last element of the list for every value, not a different element for each key.